# Bootstrap 3 - Select all options using multiple select

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following multiple select field from Bootstrap 3 framework:

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple name="regions" id="regions">
    <option value="99">All regions</option>
    <option value="AC">AC</option>
    <option value="AL">AL</option>
    <option value="AP">AP</option>
</select>
```

And its jQuery code:

```
$("#regions").change(function(){
    if($("option:selected:last",this).val() == 99){
        $('#regions option').prop('selected', true);
    } else{
        $('#regions option').prop('selected', false);
    }
});
```

The issue is: when the "All regions" option is selected, the multiple select is not updated with all the options selected.

Comment: Scratch that - [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ts4u4/) and it seems to work fine, other than the fact that your code doesn't let you select the other options... [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ts4u4/1/) that still allows you to select other options singularly, and [here's one](http://jsfiddle.net/Ts4u4/2/) that allows you to select multiple other options while still selecting all at the top.

Comment: **Note:** if you're having trouble with your original code working at all, try using `.attr('selected', 'selected')` instead of `prop()`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) component, two options:

**1. Built in**

Add

```
data-actions-box="true"
```

to your select tag in html.

If you need custom labels:

```
$.fn.selectpicker.defaults = { 
  selectAllText: "All",
  deselectAllText: "None"
}
```

**2. Manually**

You can select/deselect all options in html select and refresh the bootstrap-select component:

```
$("#your-select option").attr("selected", *value)
$("#your-select").selectpicker("refresh") // must be already initialized
*value  = true | "selected" | false | null
```

**Note:** in my tests using bootstrap-select and this approach, i could only deselect all. When i tried to select all, the component was not updated.

https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/825

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Sorry, i think i misunderstood how SO works. Now i edited the post trying to answer the question.

Comment: The correct answer is  data-actions-box="true" (plural), I edited and I gave +1 to you.

Answer (score 0):

## Hope this will help someone who has this question currently!

Im not sure what you exactly trying to achieve, if I get it correct you want to select all if user selects the first one with the `value=99` and select individuals if they select others right?

```
$("#regions").change(function(){
    var selectedValue = $("option:selected", this).val();
    if(selectedValue == 99){
        $('option', this).prop('selected', true);
    } else{
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
        $(this).siblings().prop('selected', true);
    }
});
```

See the example: https://jsfiddle.net/pwdu8wab/4/